# Product quantity increment based on product metafield

Tags: javascript, shopify, liquid

I have succeeded in getting the quantity selector on the product page to increment based on the product meta field.

This code is from my theme.js.liquid file:

```
  // Add or subtract from the current quantity
if ($el.hasClass('ajaxcart__qty--plus')) {
  qty += productMetaQtyIncr;
} else {
  qty -= productMetaQtyIncr;
  if (qty <= 0) qty = 0;
}
```

I placed this code in my theme.liquid head:

```
<script>const productMetaQtyIncr = {{ product.metafields.qty_incr.qty-incr }}</script>
```

So this works well on the product page which is fine.
However, when I go to my full page cart it goes back to incrementing by 1.
This is because it is no longer pulling the product meta field as I'm not on the product page.

If I open my AJAX sidebar cart it will update all products quantity increment based on the product page I am on, which isn't what I want.

So, my question is how can I get the quantity selector to recognise which product it is updating?

E.g. I have two products in my cart. Product A increments by 5 and Product B increments by 3.
When I got to the cart (sidebar cart or the full-page cart) it knows what the product increments by without being on the product page or even if I'm on a product page and I change a different product quantity using the sidebar cart on a product page.

Comment: Since you're making a global object with your quantities, you can spit out an array of all the appropriate metafields for products in the cart at the same time. Try  `var cartProductMetafields = {{ cart.items | map: 'product' | map: 'metafields' | map: 'qty_incr' | map: 'qty-incr' | json }}` to get an array of incrementations that's parallel to your array of items in your cart

Comment: Note that you'll probably want to merge that with proper identification data, like the item's `key`, so that when items are removed from the cart things don't get mis-aligned when an item gets removed from the cart

Comment: That should be an answer to the question and not just a comment. You could just sum it up as "render your metafields of interest into a data structure so that you can accurately distinguish one from another based on the product/variant ID. 

That is always the chore. A product has no quantity, a variant has quantity. Unless you are dealing with the simplest of Shopify products (one default variant). Hence the current approach could be a wee bit weak, unless all variants of a product run off the same overall quantity.